# How do I get information from an unknown number of checkboxes

Tags: php, html

On one of my html pages, I have loop that creates an n number of checkboxes (depends on how many entries there are in the database).

When the user presses the submit button, it opens up another html page, How do I set up my second page to receive all the ticked items. Note, the names of the checkboxes are also unknown, so far I have this on my first page:

```
 <form action='tests.php' method='get'>
                <p>
                <?php
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
                                print "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name=".$row{'Info'}." value=".$row{'Info'}.">".$row{'Info'}."<br></td></tr>";
                        }
                ?>
                </p>
                <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
```

When tests.php is opened, how do I get all the check-marked values?

Reading form other posts, I believe I have to use an array to get the values, however, I still cannot see how to implement an array here.

Comment: You'd use a `foreach`

Comment: Yes, but how would I implement the array on the page to get the checkboxed items, The number of items present cannot be predicted.

Comment: You can use an array. But you don't have to if you give each checkbox a unique name

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put them into an array:

HTML:

```
<form action='tests.php' method='get'>
    <p>
    <?php
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            print "<tr><td><input type='checkbox' name='checkbox[".$row{'Info'}."]' value=".$row{'Info'}.">".$row{'Info'}."<br></td></tr>";
        }
    ?>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

PHP:

```
$checkboxes = $_GET['checkbox']; // this is an array
foreach ($checkboxes  as $key => $value) {
    // $key is the value of $row{'Info'}
}
```

It should be noted that this will not work if your values have brackets in them unless you use `urlencode()` on them first.

Comment: Prego signore Giovanni ;-)

Comment: BTW, why `name='checkbox[".$row{'Info'}."]'` and not just `name='checkbox[]'` ? Info is already in value. (and should be `htmlspecialchar()`red)

Comment: @nl-x Honestly, I took this an opportunity to demonstrate the concept of using array notation rather than as a specific answer to their question. Hopefully then it is educational for both the OP and future readers.

Comment: @JohnConde I am quite interested in knowing, if your approach is legal HTML, how the index should be escaped

Comment: @nl-x It should be escaped just as you said in your comments, by using `htmlspecialchar()`

Comment: @JohnConde Question regarding the code, so in the php portion, checkboxes is now an array, and are the array indexes being assigned to their values? so basically the index and then value are the same?

Comment: @JohnConde I don't think `htmlspecialchars()` escapes brackets `[]` for example. So that is unsuitable/insufficient for escaping an array index name.

Comment: @user2883071 Correct. In your specific example you can use `name='checkbox[]'` and it would work well for you.